# Stackoverflow Error in Minimum Size Subarray Sum

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, runtime-error, stack-overflow

My code is not working for s=120331635 and a very long array. Please find the array here

```
http://www.filedropper.com/arraytnt
```

. I receive error **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at Solution.fsub(Solution.java:17)** which appears multiple times.

**Q. Given an array of n positive integers and a positive integer s, find the minimal length of a contiguous subarray of which the sum ≥ s. If there isn't one, return 0 instead.**

Example:

Input: s = 7, nums = [2,3,1,2,4,3]
Output: 2
Explanation: the subarray [4,3] has the minimal length under the problem constraint

class Solution{

```
public int minSubArrayLen(int s, int[] nums) {
    if(nums.length==0) return 0;
    return fsub(s,nums,0,1);
}

public int fsub(int s, int[] A, int i, int f){
    int n=A.length;

    if(f>n) return fsub(s,A,0,f-i+1);
    int sum = 0; for(int j = i;j<f;j++) {sum += A[j];}

    if(sum>=s) return(f-i);      // if found
    else if(f-i == n) return 0;  // if nothing found

    return fsub(s,A,i+1,f+1);

}
```

}

Comment: If you run through it slowly with a debugger, you’ll quickly see where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

By using recursion, on every call to the method, it uses method stack, which will take memory. So if its time complexity is O(2^n) where n is the size of the array, then its space complexity will be O(2^n) for this many methods calls. So 2^n space is crossing the given limits of memory.